# Paying off Credit Card Debt Code with Python

Tags: python

I am having difficulty writing a program to calculate the remaining balance of credit card debt after a 12 month period. This is what I currently have, however when I run the program is says that "name RBm is not defined".

```
x = float(raw_input('What is the outstanding balance on the credit card?'))
y = float(raw_input('What is the annual interest rate?'))
z = float(raw_input('What is the minimum monthly payment rate?'))
for n in range(1, 13):
    m = n-1
    RB0 = x
    MMPn = RBm*z
    IP = (y/12)*x
    PPn = MMPn - IP
    RBn = RBm - PPn
    print 'Month:', n
    print 'Minimum Monthly Payment:', MMPn
    print 'Principal Paid:', PPn
    print 'Remaining Balance:', RBn
```

Where MMP is Minimum Monthly Payment, IP is Interest Paid, PP is Principal Paid RB is Remaining Balance, and n is month number.
I was able to come up with this, where I could just copy and paste it twelve times with different numbers, however I wish to make it more efficient, so instead I came up with the above code.

```
MMP1 = RB0*z
IP = (y/12)*RB0
PP1 = MMP1 - IP
RB1 = RB0 - PP1
print 'Month: 1'
print 'Mimimum Monthly Payment:', MMP1
print 'Principal Paid:', PP1
print 'Remaining Balance:', RB1
```

Comment: So what is `RBm`?  That's your problem after all.  Read the error message!

Comment: You are trying to use `n` as a variable in a variable name. This cannot be done this easily, since Python would not know what to substitute in your variable name. So you have to declare every variable explicitly. `RBn` is just a name like `Alec`, and when you use `RBm` on the right-hand side, python does not know it yet, thus complains.

Comment: So does that mean there is no way to do this in this manner? Is there an alternative way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell your program what RBm actually is.

You use it here first:

```
MMPn = RBm*z
```

Your program does not know what to do with this variable.

Comment: So defining "m" as "m+1" and "RB0" as "x" does not suffice for definition of "RBm"?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you define m as n-1. Not that it matters, because you never defined RBm. In fact, I don't really understand what you expect RBm to be. Do you want to use m as an index for different RB_?

Comment: Oh i get it. You use m and n to "index" your RB. That does not work. Python does not understand this as "RB1" and "RB2" etc. Python just sees a variable "RBm" and does not make a connection between an existing variable "m".

Comment: Oh, I see. It worked when I did it for just n though (removing the m and defining the variables dependent on m separately). Is there a reason that it works for n, but not m in this case?

Comment: You use "RBn = RBm - PPn", and with this you tell Python "RBn is XYZ", and from there on Python knows RBn. So before oyu use RBm, you have to tell Python "RBm = ..."

Comment: Is there a way to define "RBm" as the remaining balance for the previous month (thus "RB" for "n-1")?

Comment: Lets see... you could just use RB all the time. Define RB=x before the loop. calculate MMP = RB*z. calculate the new RB with RB = RB - PP. Basically: get rid of all m and n. This taks seems like a homework for comp science python beginners. you can do it! ;)